# How to install/use Ruby gems in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda has support for Ruby 2.5, and it's straightforward to run a simple Ruby script in this environment

However, suppose your script requires some gems, how do you install and use gems in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 4):

Install the gems into the project folder by using the `--path` flag when running `bundle install`. Then include the installed dependencies in your .zip.source bundle. There are [docs on creating a Ruby bundle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-package.html).

Another option would be to create a [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html), which can make your deploys faster (smaller zip file) and be used to organize your code.